# Where can I find SMS server

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

I am in need of an SMS server or gateway. can you tell me how to get it and run it on Debian server ? 
It doesn't matter if I need to pay.
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org) gateway. They have a Debian distribution available.

If, however, you are looking to send SMS from the machine, you could purchase any one of the embedded GSM phone modules and use an existing library to send SMS like [LibSMS](http://smslib.org/) (Java library).

Comment: Is it free? is it still maintained in developement ? Last date was 2010-10-20 ..

Comment: No I want to send SMS automatically from Python so, I think I need a Gateway

Comment: The library is free. I can't say anything for the currency of the code, but the [SMS specifications](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gts/03/0340/05.03.00_60/gsmts_0340v050300p.pdf) have not changed since 1996. If you just need to send the messages, use a library and either connect to the SMS provider, or attach a GSM modem to your machine.